# About Exception Grown

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner of programming. Recently, I wrote a program to pick up day, month, year from string date and convert into int and assign to elements of an array. But VS return an error while compile which I dont really understand. Please help me to explain!
Thanks in advance!
My program

```
using namespace std;

int a[2];
int j = 0;
string str_date;
string str_date_sub;

void get_date()
{
    if (str_date.find('/') == str_date.npos)
    {
        stringstream ss(str_date);
        ss >> a[j];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= str_date.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str_date[i] == '/')
        {
            str_date_sub = str_date.substr(0, i - 1);
            str_date.erase(0, i + 1);
            stringstream ss(str_date_sub);
            ss >> a[j];
            j++;
            break;
        }
    }
    get_date();
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please input the date DD/MM/YYYY:\n";
    str_date = "12/05/1234";
    get_date();
    cout << a[1];
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

edited:
The error is here

```
ss >> a[j];
```

`Exception thrown at 0x5B03297A (msvcp140d.dll) in Project6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01116890.`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: sorry the error is here
    ss >> a[j];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three mistakes:

There are three tokens in date so

```
int a[2];
```

needs to be

```
int a[3];
```

Next in

```
str_date_sub = str_date.substr(0, i - 1);
```

The second parameter is the length of the substring, so

```
str_date_sub = str_date.substr(0, i);
```

is more appropriate.

Finally, in `get_date`

```
get_date();
```

is always called, leading to uncontrolled recursion. Eventually the program exhausts automatic storage and after that all bets are off. You only want to re enter the function if there is more string to be parsed. Easiest fix is to place a `return` at the end of

```
if (str_date.find('/') == str_date.npos)
{
    stringstream ss(str_date);
    ss >> a[j];
    return; // right here
}
```

But why stop there?

```
if (str_date.find('/') == str_date.npos)
```

found the location of the `/`, so why

```
for (int i = 0; i <= str_date.length(); i++)
```

Huh. Make that 4 bugs. `i <= str_date.length()` will go marching outside the bounds of `str_date`.

Anyway, no point for this loop. You can

```
auto pos = str_date.find('/');
```

and then use `pos` for the rest of the function.

You can also eliminate all of the global variables, but Deadpool's on so I'm logging out.

Answer (score 1):

When you reach this condition true: `(str_date.find('/') == str_date.npos)` the variable `j` contains the value 2. Under this condition you call `ss >> a[j];`, i.e. `ss >> a[2];` that tries to accesses the third element of the array of the size 2. It is access out of the array bound. You must declare `int a[3]`.

Additionally you must break your recursion when `j` accedes 2, else an improper date "12/05/12/1234" will crash your program again. At the end move call `get_date()` under condition:

```
if (j < 3)
  get_date();
```